# how to use a def function to compare all strings with all strings of list

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```py
def sequ():
  for i in range(len(new_sequ)):      
    z=1
    s1=new_sequ[z]
    s2=new_sequ[i]
    #more declaration of sx
    z+=1
```

`new_sequ` is my list with sequences. `s1` is the sequence that i compare to `s2`.

My problem is, that I dont know how to use my `def` function for all strings. I want to compare all strings with all strings. In my code I wrote the code to read the function to compare the 0th element/string of my list with the other 35 strings of the list. How could i continue to compare the 1st element with the other, the 2nd with the rest and so on.

I would appreciate your help.

Cheers,
Pap

Comment: Include the relevant code properly formatted in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Questions on SO should be self-contained. Questions that do not contain the relevant information or have links to code, are likely to be downvoted and closed. Copy the code, [edit] the question and include the code in a code block.

Comment: Ok i have edit my question and put the relevant code in it. Thank you

Comment: Could you not just declare a variable outside the function, say `my_val` and initialise it to `None` or `''`. Then on the first iteration, assign the 0th string to `my_val` and from that point forward, compare each subsequent string to `my_val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
You could also use itertools, as this will give combinations as suggested in the comment.

```
import itertools

new_sequ = [1,2,3,4]
for s1,s2 in itertools.combinations(new_sequ,2):
    print(s1,s2)
```

You're going to want to have two for-loops, one in the other, like this:

```
match = list()
for i in range(len(new_sequ)):
    for j in range(len(new_sequ)):
        if new_sequ[i] == new_sequ[j]: #since we would like to find the matches.
            match.append(new_sequ[i])
```

If you don't care about the indices, and just want the strs, you could also use:

```
for s1 in new_sequ:
    for s2 in new_sequ:
        pass
```

Or you could use enumerate:

```
for i1,s1 in enumerate(new_sequ):
    for i2,s2 in enumerate(new_sequ):
        pass
```

Comment: i want to read the def function to see combination for all strings in my list.

Comment: In that case, use the top one.